# Autofit row height in reporting services 2012 (SSRS)

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

I'm creating reports in reporting services 2012 and i want my report rows to be autofit as my data is dynamically created and it differs in height from row to row.Now i have tried to give the row properties CanGrow and CanShrink to true,so that as it mentioned here:[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa194086(office.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa194086%28office.10%29.aspx)
my report rows become fit to the data they are bound to but it's not working at all(all rows grow much taller than the contents).any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to add a screenshot of what you're experiencing, and a description of your desired result?

Comment: CanGrow should do the trick, at least it does in SSRS2008. Are you sure you don't have a lot of blank characters in the fields? Try to use trim() in dataset you are using. Also, CanGrow expands the cell to fit the column which has the most data, so not only the cell with CanGrow as true will be expanded, other cells will too.

Comment: facing the same problem, @behrad-farsi you did not find a soluction or did you?

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, you could try playing with the visibility of a particular textbox under the column that is appearing to oversized. Changing the visibility of the textbox to toggle on the column header label.

Or make sure your report margins are correct and use wordwrap.

Hope this helps!